# /sys: cpio: chown failed - Read-only file system (Building Passenger RPM using Docker)

Tags: centos, rpm, docker

While I'm trying to build rpm using [Docker](http://docker.com) for Phusion Passenger 4.0.53 (https://github.com/phusion/passenger_rpm_automation), I get the following error. Any help is most appreciated.

```
$ ./build -p /srv/passenger_rpm_automation/passenger -P /srv/passenger_rpm_automation/passenger-release-4.0.53 -o /srv/passenger_rpm_automation/out -d 'el6' -a 'x86_64' -c /srv/passenger_rpm_automation/cache

.
.
rpm:passenger:el6:x86_64: 2014-12-11 15:17:10 -- Error unpacking rpm package filesystem-2.4.30-3.el6.x86_64
rpm:passenger:el6:x86_64: 2014-12-11 15:17:10 -- error: unpacking of archive failed on file /sys: cpio: chown failed - Read-only file system
rpm:passenger:el6:x86_64: 2014-12-11 15:17:10 -- /usr/share/info/dir: could not read (No such file or directory) and could not create (No such file or directory)
rpm:passenger:el6:x86_64: 2014-12-11 15:17:10 -- /usr/share/info/dir: could not read (No such file or directory) and could not create (No such file or directory)
.
.
.
rpm:passenger:el6:x86_64: 2014-12-11 15:17:10 --   xz-lzma-compat.x86_64 0:4.999.9-0.5.beta.20091007git.el6
rpm:passenger:el6:x86_64: 2014-12-11 15:17:10 --   zlib.x86_64 0:1.2.3-29.el6
rpm:passenger:el6:x86_64: 2014-12-11 15:17:10 --
rpm:passenger:el6:x86_64: 2014-12-11 15:17:10 -- Failed:
rpm:passenger:el6:x86_64: 2014-12-11 15:17:10 --   filesystem.x86_64 0:2.4.30-3.el6
rpm:passenger:el6:x86_64: 2014-12-11 15:17:10 --
rpm:passenger:el6:x86_64: 2014-12-11 15:17:10 --
rpm:passenger:el6:x86_64: 2014-12-11 15:17:10 -- DEBUG: kill orphans
*** Command failed: /usr/bin/mock --verbose  -r epel-6-x86_64 --resultdir '/output/el6-x86_64' --uniqueext passenger-el6-x86_64 rebuild /output/el6-x86_64/passenger-4.0.52-1.el6.src.rpm
----- Task errored: Building binary RPMs -> passenger:el6:x86_64 -----
---------------------------------------------
Current time: 2014-12-11 15:17:10
Start time  : 2014-12-11 15:15:45
Duration    : 1 min 24 sec
```

Environment:
Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64bit
Docker version 1.3.2

Answer (score 0):

May be the filesystem mounted at `/srv` or `/` is read-only. You should look at the output of `/proc/mounts`. Example output:

```
rootfs / rootfs rw 0 0
/dev/root / ext3 rw,noatime,errors=continue,barrier=1,data=ordered 0 0
devtmpfs /dev devtmpfs rw,size=247996k,nr_inodes=61999,mode=755 0 0
none /proc proc rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
none /sys sysfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
/proc/bus/usb /proc/bus/usb usbfs rw,relatime 0 0
/dev/vda2 /boot ext3 ro,noatime,errors=continue,barrier=1,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/vda9 /var ext3 rw,noatime,errors=continue,barrier=1,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/vda10 /data ext3 rw,noatime,errors=continue,barrier=1,data=ordered 0 0
tmpfs /dev/shm tmpfs rw,relatime 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000 0 0
tmpfs /vtmp tmpfs rw,relatime,size=65536k 0 0
```

Search for lines with `ro` as the value in the fourth field. Example line from the output, above:

```
/dev/vda2 /boot ext3 ro,noatime,errors=continue,barrier=1,data=ordered 0 0
```

Then remount the filesystem in read-write mode. Note that if you usually have a filesystem that is mounted read-only then it must be for a good reason. Be sure to consult your system administrator.

Comment: I don't know the parameter syntax of the tools involved, but note that OP also asks about /sys.